# hbase adding phoenix jars under cloudera

Tags: jar, hbase, cloudera, cloudera-manager, apache-phoenix

I'm looking for a way to add the Phoenix Project (http://phoenix.incubator.apache.org/) JAR's to an HBase region server running under CDH 4.5 Cloudera.

There are several mentions in the googlecanon about /usr/lib/.. but this CDH packages at least the hbase dependencies under dirs such as: /usr/share/cmf/lib/cdh4/hbase-0.94.6-cdh4.5.0.jar

I was looking for a way under the Cloudera Manager.  Ideally, we'd be able to deploy dependencies like Phoenix under HDFS or similar.

Anybody try this integration?

Answer (score 0):

i am using CDH 4.7 and i have been working with phoenix form past 2-3 months. Its working fine...

below is the instruction i followed...
Phoenix version 2.2.2

copied phoenix-2.2.2.jar to all region servers hbase lib which is under parcels directory (for me its under /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-4.7.7-*/lib/hbase/lib

then used phoenix-2.2.2 client.jar to create,upload data to tables

note: you should mention zookeeper quorem server for client.jar

Comment: Thanks, Bhuvan.  We eventually worked it out, and HBase was working happily within our cluster.  Glad your experience is also positive.